# Windows Vista hangs on startup for a reeeaal long time

Tags: windows-vista, operating-systems, freeze, boot

I have an Acer Aspire 5735Z laptop with Windows Vista (legal.)

After the login screen, when the sidebar is loading, the OS hangs for like 10 minutes or so. When hovering over the icons on the desktop there is no reaction from the OS (no hover states are shown.) When hovering over the taskbar and quicklaunch icons, the "loading" cursor appears.

Is there any way to figure out what is causing this hang? There have been no changes to the sidebar functionality, although there was a recent OS update done.

Comment: you might try taking a look at these:  [How do I create a memory dump of my computer freeze or crash?](http://superuser.com/questions/224496/how-do-i-create-a-memory-dump-of-my-computer-freeze-or-crash) and [How do I troubleshoot hardware issues related to a computer freeze/crash?](http://superuser.com/questions/224515/how-do-i-troubleshoot-hardware-issues-related-to-a-computer-freeze-crash) and [How do I troubleshoot computer dumps?](http://superuser.com/questions/224505/how-do-i-troubleshoot-computer-dumps) as a starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one would be to disable the sidebar to see if this is the problem. If it is, re-enable it and then remove sidebar applets one at a time until you find the culprit. Start with any applets that connect to the internet for data. Don't worry about whether you need the applet running at this point: the idea is to find the problem. Once you find the cause, then you decide how to best resolve it.

If the problem still occurs after disabling sidebar, start turning off applications that run at startup. Use msconfig and uncheck items that run at startup.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, if I find any culprit, I'll update. :)